# How many full nodes on the tezos network?

Tags: node, network

I would like to know where i can get the information about the actual number of full nodes powering the Tezos network.

I suppose if some info is available is likely a lower bound given that a number of nodes are probably hiding behing proxy-nodes (like bakers eg), however a lower bound would be good enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I found https://tzscan.io/network?state=all via [this Reddit post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/aqaig3/how_many_nodes_are_running_the_tezos_network/) where the current amount is around 6 800 nodes.

There are two directions this amount maybe is not the absolute one, though:

A) post says it does not count private nodes nor self bakers

B) without state = all the amount was 79, which is significantly lower, denoting most probably ones currently active.

So, hard to say. Maybe Tzscan.io API would reveal which number to believe.

This is sitation under Network in the API:

> The Network is the list of Nodes running the Tezos Server Application. From any Node, including the Nodes used by Tz-Scan, only a partial part of the full network is visible, mostly through the Node to which the Node could successfully connect.

Comment: ?state=all gives the list of peers TzScan nodes saw at least once. This doesn't mean that these peers are still running. The same node instance with a different identity and/or IP address might be considered more that once.

Comment: without ?state=all, TzScan only shows the nodes it's connected to. There are actually more (non private) nodes in the network. You can try to start a node with --connections 10000 to connect to as much peers as possible.